# ImportError when trying to import Prov Module in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror, python-module, easy-install

I'm getting this error when trying to import a module from the Prov package.
Here is the contents of my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import sys
egg_path='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/prov-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/prov'
sys.path.append(egg_path)
#... rest of code
import model as prov

def main():
    # Create a new provenance document
    d1 = ProvDocument()  # d1 is now an empty provenance document
    # Declaring namespaces for various prefixes used in the example
    d1.add_namespace('now', 'http://www.provbook.org/nownews/')
    d1.add_namespace('nowpeople', 'http://www.provbook.org/nownews/people/')
    d1.add_namespace('bk', 'http://www.provbook.org/ns/#')

    # Entity: now:employment-article-v1.html
    e1 = d1.entity('now:employment-article-v1.html')
    # Agent: nowpeople:Bob
    d1.agent('nowpeople:Bob')
```

And here is the output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prov.py", line 6, in <module>
    import model as prov
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/prov-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/prov/model.py", line 25, in <module>
    from prov import Error, serializers
ImportError: cannot import name Error`

Any ideas or fixes? I installed Prov using easy_install prov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. The name of my file that I was trying to import into was also called prov.py . It was a circular dependency issue.

Thank you guys for such quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your module file `prov.py`. It prevents import of the third-party library because the module name conflicts.

Make sure `prov.pyc` is removed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? The file that I'm trying to import is called model, which tries to import a Error and Serializers from a file called prov.. however, I don't see a prov in the package.

Comment: ahh I fixed it! My file that I was using was also called prov.py so It was a circular dependency.

Comment: `from prov import Error, serializers` tries to import `prov`; instead of `prov` of the package `prov`, your module named `prov` is imported. Try to add following line at the beginning of your file: `import prov; print(prov)`